# Interstitial iAd implementation

Tags: ios, xcode, iad, interstitial

I am facing problems with iAd fullscreen ad. 
I implement iAd like:

```
 -(void)showFullScreenAd {
     //Check if already requesting ad
     if (requestingAd == NO) {
         [ADInterstitialAd release];
          interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
          interstitial.delegate = self;
          self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;
         [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
         NSLog(@"interstitialAdREQUEST");
         requestingAd = YES;
     }//end if
 }

 -(void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
     interstitial = nil;
     [interstitialAd release];
     [ADInterstitialAd release];
     requestingAd = NO;
     NSLog(@"interstitialAd didFailWithERROR");
     NSLog(@"%@", error);
 }

  -(void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
     NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidLOAD");
     if (interstitialAd != nil && interstitial != nil && requestingAd == YES)      {
         [interstitial presentFromViewController:self];
         NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidPRESENT");
     }//end if
 }

 -(void)interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
     interstitial = nil;
     [interstitialAd release];
     [ADInterstitialAd release];
     requestingAd = NO;
     NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidUNLOAD");
 }

 -(void)interstitialAdActionDidFinish:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
     interstitial = nil;
[interstitialAd release];
 [ADInterstitialAd release];
  requestingAd = NO;
  NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidFINISH");
  }
```

I am calling "showFullScreenAd" to present ad. But after calling it for 10 times i get this message, even if I dismiss this View Controller and setting interstitial = nill,:

WARNING: More than 10 instances of ADBannerView or ADInterstitialView currently exist. This is a misuse of the iAd API, and ad performance will suffer as a result. This message is printed only once.

Problem is with dismissing interstitial i guess. Because statement
     interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];

every time makes new instance of interstitial.

I seen few topics about this, but no answer how to properly dismiss those instances.

Comment: 2015, not using ARC.

Comment: @kelin what did you mean with that? Can you explain me please?

Answer (score -1):

You need to call method in `viewDidLoad`.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
  [self showFullScreenAd];
}
```

I had this problem when I called the method in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.